# Multiple sort collection

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, custom-attributes, sort

When I am in the listening product when I mark order alphabet by name I want to use two attributes. First my attribute, later name.

This is my structure name product: my_attribute name_product

I want to sort first by my_attribute when value my_attriute is the same I want to filter by name product.

I try to modify setCollection method in **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar**(later I create custom module) but this is no work. I tried **$collection->setOrder('my_attribute, name', asc)** not work. When in this function I dump ids product sort is ok, but somewhere this sort is overridden. Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `setOrder` to collection using two attributes,You can use the below code

`$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('my_attribute ASC, name ASC'));`

I think it will work perfectly.

Try and let me know, If it's works.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setOrder()` or `getSelect()->order()` multiple times, like

```
$collection->setOrder('my_attribute', Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC);
$collection->setOrder('name', Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC);
```

`getSelect()->order(...)` also accepts an array as parameter ...

```
$orderBy = array(
    'my_attribute ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC,
    'name ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC
);

$collection->getSelect()->order($orderBy);
```

... there is also a fallback to ascending order ...

```
$collection->getSelect()->order(array('my_attribute', 'name'));
```

<sup>**Note:** fallback for `setOrder()` depends on collection type, so better add direction there.</sup>